# Useful Features of Semantic Graphs

Tags: semantics, nlp, software

If this question is too general, please let me know, and I will revise it.

I am developing a program that measures all sorts of "features" of a sentence, everything from sentence length, to average word length, to lexical diversity. I'd also like to incorporate some features of the semantic graphs of the sentences.

What are some suggestions as to useful features of the graph to extract? I'm just looking for a handful, to get the ball rolling, and then develop them further for my specific needs.

Any reading suggestions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not actually a book, but certainly a helpful research is located [in this site](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon) (interface that provides online access to the LinGO English Resource Grammar).

Here's the semantic graph it has created from the first sentence of your question:

[image: Semantic graph]